# Regex replace random number

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that would allow me to find and replace all instances of strings ending with random numbers, e.g.:

Replace all instances of **'/app/build/js/app.min.js?r=123456789**

with **'/app/build/js/app.min.js?r=' + newValue**

I tried the following (in JavaScript), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var before = '/app/build/js/app.min.js?r=/[0-9]/g';
```

I need this for a gulp task, which looks like the following:

```
  gulp.src(myFile)
    .pipe(replace(before, after))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(myPath));
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will only match 1 number. You want to match multiple numbers, so instead of `[0-9]`, use:

`\d+$`

Which will match one more more numbers coming as the very last thing in the string.